Generate output from PyParsing tree
Ive created a very large PyParsing tree from reading ISB Bind9 named.conf file.
Now I wish to redirect my attention to generating an output back to the way it was syntactically read and created from.
I see a close answer and example for a JSON output in StackOverflow.
Is there a small working example for a custom output/generator Python class, mostly to support recreation from what was read into the tree?

Interesting question. I would not see much value in having pyparsing just regenerate the original text, but what if you used your parser to normalize the input syntax into a more standardized form?  Can you post some example input text, and how you would like to see it reconstructed after running through pyparsing?  (My initial thoughts at implementing such a thing would be to use parse actions to create structured data objects, and then have a method on those classes to emit their contents in the standard form.)
